# Save in windows forms application

Tags: windows, windows-10, autosave, winforms

I made a simple winforms app with a **checkbox** and when I **check** it I want to **save** that its checked so when the user closes the form then **reopens** it, its **still checked**. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application Settings to save the app state.

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.check = checkBox1.Checked;

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.check;
    }
```

[Here's the YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7to8KHsXspE)